# Akka-Http WebSocket: Akka stream use WebSocket as a sink

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Using Akka-Http and Akka-Streams version 2.4 how can I construct a stream so that it has a sink that is a websocket.

For example I would like to have a source that generates random numbers, these numbers get filtered, lets say keep even numbers, then flow to a WebSocket as a sink.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code put into a akka http route will output a continuous stream of random numbers without overwhelming the websocket

```
path("randomNums") {
  val src =
    Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt()))
          .filter(i => i > 0 && i % 2 == 0).map(i => TextMessage(i.toString))

    extractUpgradeToWebsocket { upgrade =>
      complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, src))
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for the example. If I wanted to send the same stream to all connected clients would I have to keep a set of their actorRef's, added their actorRefs when they connect. Then when theres a number ready to be pushed to them iterate through the set?

Comment: (disclaimer: partly guessing): The part after `upgrade =>` is being separately invoked for each new Websocket connection. Therefore, you would need to create a source dynamically, there. Look for `BroadcastHub` for splitting one root stream to 0..n separate ones. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#Dynamic_fan-in_and_fan-out_with_MergeHub_and_BroadcastHub